# Visual Studio Custom start page for project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a custom start page for a custom template using Visual Studio.

What am I trying to achieve?

When a user creates a new project using my custom template from VS menu I would like to show a page after the creation of that project in Visual Studio similar to the below-mentioned page.

[image: Similar page of this kind]

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?  What part do you need help with and what have you done so far?

Comment: I have created a new project template where the user can create a new project based on that template.
When the project is created I want the user to show a custom start page/ Overview page as its displayed when you create a new ASP.NET Core project.

Is my question clear now?

Comment: Right, but what's the problem?

Comment: I couldn't find the documentation on how to create those custom overview pages

Comment: Questions seeking documentation links are not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but is [How to: Use wizards with project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates) what you're looking for?  Or [Creating a custom Start Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-custom-start-page)?

Comment: How can I create a page like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTMe9.png) for my Custom Visual Studio template